# No data is getting inserted into my database using PreparedStatement

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, prepared-statement

I have a method below that uses `preparedStatements` to insert data into my SQL database. Currently it is weather data that gets inserted to `mydb.weather_data`. For some reason, I have no trouble connecting to my database (not getting any connection errors), but no data actually get inserted into my DB.

I was wondering what the issue would be? The numbers below are all dummy data to test insertion.

The `type` for my five columns are respectively `varChar(10)` and `Int` for the rest of the four.

```
private static void batchInsertRecordsIntoTable() throws SQLException{
        Connection dbConnection = null;
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;

        String insertTableSQL = "INSERT INTO `mydb`.`weather_data`" 
                + "(`dateTime`,`hourlyTemp`,`dewPoint`,`windSpeed`,`relHum`) VALUES" 
                + "(?,?,?,?,?)";
        try{
            dbConnection = getDBConnection();
            preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(insertTableSQL);

            dbConnection.setAutoCommit(false);

            preparedStatement.setString(1, "1111111111"); // dateTime
            preparedStatement.setInt(2, 12); // hourlyTemp
            preparedStatement.setInt(3, 12); // dewPoint
            preparedStatement.setInt(4, 12); //windSpped
            preparedStatement.setInt(5, 12); //relHum
            preparedStatement.addBatch();

            preparedStatement.executeBatch();

            dbConnection.commit();

            System.out.println("Record was inserted into mydb weather_data");

        }catch(SQLException e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            dbConnection.rollback();
        }finally{
            if(preparedStatement!=null){
                preparedStatement.close();
            }
            if(dbConnection!=null){
                dbConnection.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You really don't need to quote your table and column names.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I read somewhere that it is good practice to do so, and I don't think that part is the issue.

Comment: datetime may be throwing an error... can you try to manually insert that same data set and see if it complains about syntax?

Comment: ditto what Randy said, is date time an actual date-time column in the db?

Comment: @Randy Using MySQL Workbench, I have no issue with inserting that data. In all honestly I literally copy and pasted the query that it generates from the GUI into my code.

Comment: so just to clarify, dateTime is a String? or Date?

Comment: And to clarify further, no exception gets printed to the console?

Comment: Please do not use `System.out.println(e.getMessage());`. If you don't have a logger, at least use `e.printStacktrace(System.out)`.

Comment: @Randy It's a `String`. It's actually a unix-format data-number.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Thanks I will change it - good point, I wasn't at the time aware that I was using System.out();

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private static void batchInsertRecordsIntoTable() throws SQLException{
        Connection dbConnection = null;
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;

        String insertTableSQL = "INSERT INTO mydb.weather_data" 
                + "(dateTime,hourlyTemp,dewPoint,windSpeed,relHum) VALUES" 
                + "(?,?,?,?,?)";
        try{
            dbConnection = getDBConnection();
            preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(insertTableSQL);

            dbConnection.setAutoCommit(false);

            preparedStatement.setString(1, "1111111111"); // dateTime
            preparedStatement.setInt(2, 12); // hourlyTemp
            preparedStatement.setInt(3, 12); // dewPoint
            preparedStatement.setInt(4, 12); //windSpped
            preparedStatement.setInt(5, 12); //relHum

            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

            dbConnection.commit();

            System.out.println("Record was inserted into mydb weather_data");

        }catch(SQLException e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            dbConnection.rollback();
        }finally{
            if(preparedStatement!=null){
                preparedStatement.close();
            }
            if(dbConnection!=null){
                dbConnection.close();
            }
        }
    }
```